# Cannot change background color of AlertDialog button

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat, material-components-android

I'm trying to change the color of the AlertDialog with likely all solutions defined for this issue in stackoverflow and it still doesn't work.

This is the code I'm using to try to achieve that:

```
 val vacationDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(fragment.context,R.style.DialogTheme)
 val factory = LayoutInflater.from(OtrosDetailFragment.fragment.context);
 var view = factory.inflate(R.layout.sample, null)
 [...]
 vacationDialog.setView(view)
        val window = vacationDialog.create()
 vacationDialog.setPositiveButton("Cerrar"){dialog, which ->
            dialog.dismiss()

        }

 /**Listener called when the AlertDialog is shown**/


 vacationDialog.show()

 window.setOnShowListener {

 /**Get the positive button from the AlertDialog**/
 val positiveButton = window.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)

 /**Set your color to the positive button**/
 positiveButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(fragment.context!!, R.color.colorPrimary))
 positiveButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(fragment.context!!, R.color.colorPrimary))
 positiveButton.setHintTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(fragment.context!!, R.color.colorPrimary))
 positiveButton.setLinkTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(fragment.context!!, R.color.colorPrimary))
        }
```

This is the style DialogTheme defined in styles.xml, in which, by the way, I cannot find a way to change the default button color (black), and seems to override any change tried from code.

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">

        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <!-- No backgrounds, titles or window float -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>


    </style>
```

Any idea on how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using an **`AppCompat`** theme you can use something like:

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <!-- Used for the buttons -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#FFCC00</item>
        <!-- Used for the title and text -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <!-- Used for the background -->
        <item name="android:background">#5fa3d0</item>
</style>
```

[image]

With the new [**Material** components for android library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) you can use the new [`androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertDialog.html).

Just use something like:

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle("Dialog")
            .setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor ....")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", /* listener = */ null)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", /* listener = */ null)
            .show();
```

You can customize your theme with something like:

```
  <!-- Alert Dialog -->
  <style name="MyThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog</item>
  </style>
```

and:

```
  <style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/selector_bt</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use `custom layout` then you can change anything easily. Follow the code below:

```
private fun showAlertDialog(activity: Activity){
    val dialog = Dialog(activity)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout)
    dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
    dialog.show()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can create your custom layout for AlertDialog and inflate it in your custom class extending AlertDialog.
- Use androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog rather than normal android.app.AlertDialog